# Display tag customize pagination href

Tags: jsp, href, displaytag

I have to customize my display tag pagination from display table.

Now I have:

```
<a href="...&d-49489-p=2 ">2</a>
```

and I want:

```
<a href="...&page=2 ">2</a>
```

How can I do this?

In my page i have links like "&d-49489-p=2" to change pages .
And i want format the links as : "&page=2"

an example of page : https://www.paginemail.it/dir/c/alimentazione/ristorazione-locali-pubblici-affini/bar-caffe/11660/lombardia/milano/milano.htm

[image]

i want to customize the pagination links

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!